# MFC OK/Cancel Dialog Button Override?

Tags: c++, button, mfc

**Language:** C++

**Development Environment:** Microsoft Visual C++

**Libraries Used:** MFC

Pretty new to MFC, so bear with me. I have a dialog that is launched via DoModal(). I'm attempting to add buttons to this dialog that will replace the default "OK" and "Cancel" buttons. Right now, I can't quite figure out how to do this. I deleted the OK and Cancel buttons and added new ones with new IDs, added event handlers, and just some simple code for them to execute upon being pressed, but I couldn't get it to work.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that DoModal() expects responses from OK or Cancel, but nothing else. I'm not really sure though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Stripped down code added for reference.

```
void CPrefsDlg::Launch() {

[ ... ]

  CSAPrefsDialog dlg;

  INT_PTR nRet = -1;
  nRet = dlg.DoModal();

  // Handle the return value from DoModal
  switch ( nRet )
  {
  case -1: 
     AfxMessageBox("Dialog box could not be created!");
     break;
  case IDABORT:
     // Do something
     break;
  case IDOK: // This works just fine.
     exit(0);
     break;
  case IDSAVEONE: // This does not work.
     MessageBox("Save One");
     break;
  default:
     break;
  };
}

void CPrefsDlg::SaveOne()
{
// I tried adding in my own handler for 'Save One'...this does not work.
MessageBox("Save one");
}
```

Comment: @Jon: You need to post some code that demonstrates the problem, and specify what you mean by "I couldn't get it to work".

Comment: I have added in some code. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @Rup Edited the code above to reflect what I previously had which also did not work.

Comment: Can you see what value you do get returned when you click save one? Your ::SaveOne handler won't work unless you wire it up into the message map macros - can't remember the syntax you need, sorry, but the class wizard should do that for you.

Comment: ... and the handler function needs to be on the dialog class, not the calling class, too.

Comment: If you're referring to afx_msg void SaveOne(); - I have this in my header. Or do you mean something different? The wizard did some work for me, yeah, but it's still being flaky and not working when I click it. If you're out of ideas, that's fine :) I do appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: No, I meant `ON_BN_CLICKED(IDSAVEONE, &CSAPrefsDialog::SaveOne)` in the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` section of the CSAPrefsDialog class. This will be auto-created for you if you add the click handler from the dialog editor.

Comment: @Rup That was it! I hadn't added in the macro for the function/button click. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To wire up your dialog to terminate and return IDSAVEONE, you need to add a click handler to the Save One button and have it call EndDialog:

```
void CSAPrefsDialog::OnBnClickedSaveone()
{
    EndDialog(IDSAVEONE);
}
```

If you add the click handler through the dialog editor (e.g. by double-clicking on your button) then the necessary framework code will be generated for you to wire this up; otherwise you'll need to add the following line into your `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` section in your dialog class:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDSAVEONE, &CSAPrefsDialog::OnBnClickedSaveone)
```

but (as AJG85's just beaten me to posting) depending on what the operation is, how fast it is and whether you want to report errors in the preferences dialog or not, you may want to just carry out the extra function in your on-clicked handler instead.

Comment: I decided to award you the best answer since you walked me through it...I actually used your comment to figure it out, and AJ posted something similar. I wish I could give it to you both, but I'll give it to you :)

Comment: +1: for `EndDialog` which I left out as an option if he wanted to close it and signal the save button being clicked.

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for AJG from me too. Sorry it took me so long to figure this out - I haven't worked with MFC for years.

Answer (score 4):

MFC has built in ids for the ok and cancel buttons. Those being IDOK and IDCANCEL. You can either handle these in a switch via the return of `DoModal()` or probably better would be to override `OnOK()` and `OnCancel()` methods in your dialog class to do what you want.

You can do this by adding a line to the message map to call your handler:

**Edit:** The same thing works for buttons you add to the dialog which I added to my example code below:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDialog, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDSAVEONE, &OnBnClickedSave)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void MyDialog::OnBnClickedOk()
{
   // do extra stuff when they click OK

   CDialog::OnOK(); // call base class version to complete normal behavior
}

void MyDialog::OnBnClickedSave()
{
   // this would be called for your save button with custom id IDSAVEONE

   // note: no base class call here as it's specific to your dialog
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that OnCancel is also called if you hit the Esc key or click the close (X) button in the upper right corner of the dialog.

Comment: @Mark good note, likewise the button set to be the accept button will be fired when pressing Enter which is `OnOK` by default. I believe the property for this is named _Default Button_